# Blocks and retain cycle for int variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, cycle

In following code I've created a weak reference to self to avoid retain cycle .Ok
The problem is that xCode gives me the same warning "capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle" for "currentPage" variable which is an int variable. How come "currentPage" lead to a retain cycle while it is a non objective-c object pointer type

```
__weak CoresspondenceDetailsViewController *weakself = self;
[tableViewBackground.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^
 {
    [weakself getPrivateCorrespondencesForPage:currentPage];
 }
```

image showing the strange warning.

[image]

thank you

Comment: Try cleaning your project (cmd+K), sometimes old errors stick up.

Comment: I believe this is not the reason ,I already did that.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is easily!
If your variable currentPage is ivar of your view controller then the actual result of accessing this variable will be look like

`self->currentPage`

which is obviously lead to retaining of self.

Two possible solutions:

```
__weak CoresspondenceDetailsViewController *weakSelf = self;
int page = currentPage;
[tableViewBackground.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^
{
  CoresspondenceDetailsViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
  if (strongSelf) {
    [strongSelf getPrivateCorrespondencesForPage:page];
  }
}
```

or

```
__weak CoresspondenceDetailsViewController *weakSelf = self;
[tableViewBackground.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^
{
  CoresspondenceDetailsViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
  if (strongSelf) {
    [strongSelf getPrivateCorrespondencesForPage:strongSelf->currentPage];
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I updated code, according the lovely comments below. Indeed, it's recommended by Apple way of working with self in blocks.

Comment: It's not safe to access ivars of weak referenced objects. In fact, I think the compiler produces an error. You have to create a strong reference inside the block **and** check that it's non-`nil` before dereferencing it.

Comment: @KenThomases a receiver doesn't need to be checked for `nil`. But it might happen (IMHO) that a weak receiver which is non-nil at the start of a method gets deallocated when the method is executing (according clang's docs receivers won't be retained when they receive a message)

Comment: thank you first solution works fine, second solution produces an error "Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed due to possible null value caused by race condition, assign it to strong variable first"

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, it's not about sending a message to a weakly-referenced object, it's about the ivar access using `->`. The weak variable may be `nil`, which would make the dereference an access violation.

Answer (score 1):

`currentPage` seems to be an ivar, thus you get the warning - since accessing an ivar requires an implicit self.

There would be two solutions, which are not strictly equal:

```
__weak CoresspondenceDetailsViewController *weakself = self;
[tableViewBackground.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^
 {
    CoresspondenceDetailsViewController* strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf getPrivateCorrespondencesForPage:strongSelf.currentPage];
 }
```

or

```
NSInteger cp = self.currentPage;
__weak CoresspondenceDetailsViewController *weakself = self;
[tableViewBackground.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^
 {
    CoresspondenceDetailsViewController* strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf getPrivateCorrespondencesForPage:cp];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self
```